# python meta characters fix

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to automatically compile meta characters in a string or regular expression in python?

I know in Perl you can use quotemeta to do this.

So that for example `.` would become `\.`

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) function for this. As stated from the documentation..

> Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.escape('foo.bar')
'foo\\.bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

See the `re.escape()` function:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.escape('.')
'\\.'
```